# ios html5 geolocation - no error when browser has no rights to use geolocation

Tags: javascript, ios, html

When using html5 geolocation, everything works nicely in the computer browser, but after switching to an iphone I get no error when user has phone settings set to not allow browser to use geolocation, is there any way to trigger error in such situation?
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleSuccess, handleError)`
I'm using this code to get current position and my `handleError` is never triggered

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to validate the object navigator.geolocation ?

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        throw "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition() {
    // my code
}
getLocation();
```

Comment: yuup, but navigator.geolocation still returns object even though it is disabled in the settings